# Powering a modem over extreme distance (~2k feet)

Tags: power, distance

We live in a rural area and have about a 2000 foot run from the end of our driveway to our house. The cable company wanted quite a bit of money to run internet to our house, but there's a drop at the end of our driveway, so we convinced them to put a modem there, and are sending the signal over a directional parabolic antenna to our house (which is being picked up by a repeater at the house using a second directional parabolic antenna). That all works great!

The modem itself is 12v, 1.5a, and originally I thought I could get away with having a marine battery and a 30w solar panel. That works fine during the day, but at night, the battery is drawn low enough that the panel can't charge it back to full and power the modem at the same time.

I could upgrade the panel to something which would handle it (around a 230w panel), but I wondered if I could get away somehow with running power from our house to the end of the driveway. I only need to end up with 12v / 1.5a, so I'm wondering if I can somehow get away with 14 awg. I am (obviously) not an EE, but I didn't know if I could use a step up transformer to reboost the signal at the end over that far of a distance.

I'm open to other ideas - we've already called the power company about doing a service pole, since we're about 30' from a transformer. Just trying to understand the calculations on running power long distance, or what else is out there.

Comment: If you are going to run cables for power, you might as well run cables for data, and put the modem in your house where you already have power. Also, 2000 feet is not "extreme distance". Consider telephone networks. 2000 feet is nothing.

Comment: We can't put the modem in the house, because the drop is at the end of the driveway from the cable company - and they can only go 400'. And yes - sorry for the hyperbole - perhaps I was just thinking in the context of a normal residential install.

Comment: Seems the easiest thing would be a bigger solar panel & a better battery. As Erik's answer points out, low voltage DC does not travel well, so you'd be best off running mains cable down with a transformer to power the modem.

Comment: @user34420 are you sure the 400' limit is some technical restriction, and not just the length they are willing to run for you? I don't know the electrical details of cable cabling, but I'd think if they already got the data to your house (many miles), then the difference between 400' and 2000' isn't that significant.

Comment: After 400', they have to put signal repeaters in, which is where the cost goes up. They wanted $11k to do the run to the house from the road, which is why we are going this way. We use too much data for satellite internet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2000' of 14 guage wire = 4000' * .003 Ohms per foot = 12 Ohms.

Voltage drop at 1.5 amps is going to be 18 volts, you would have to feed it with 18+12, which isn't a good option.

12v*1.5a=18watts, 18 watts / 75% efficient switcher/transformer = 25watts / 120v = 0.2 amps.

A better option would be 120v, which would calculate to around 0.2 amps, for a 2.4 volt drop, which could work.  However, protecting your electrical system from lightning gets difficult with two systems operating 2000 feet away, yet connected.  If it is fiber, isolating the modem may be best.

Note that the 120v neutral is probably just as dangerous as the hot at these kinds of distances.

All in all, consider yourself lucky that you can get cable internet in a rural area.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking 120v down there. I have a grounding and lightning rod already attached, which should help, but thanks for the thinking around that. So 14awg at 2000' with 120v should get be about 117v at the other end if I understand your calculations correctly?

Comment: Thats my calculations, based on quickly found .003 ohms per foot figure.  I would use a single grounding rod, and a good surge protector.  Note that this line could also bring surges into your breaker panel, it may not hurt to protect both ends with an MOV style protector.